# Get parameters from Test Azure to C# automated testing

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, automated-tests, nunit

I have a test plan solution on Azure DevOps, where I can run my manual tests with different parameters. How do i get these parameters to work with my automated testing? How do i get these parameters, which are set in Azure Test plan under a specific test case, into my code?

```cs
[Test]
public void TestBroedGoogle()
{
    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
    IWebElement q = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
    var searchText = TestContext.Parameters.Get("SearchText", "Soup");
    q.SendKeys(searchText);
    q.Submit();
    BasicMethodHelper.Waitsec(10);
    Assert.That(_driver.Title.Contains("Soup"), "Title was incorrect");
}
```

Comment: I tried to look into the RestAPI for Azure.. But that seems like such an overkill... Aren't there any other way?

Comment: NUnit supports [parameterized tests](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parameterized-Tests). Maybe use that instead of parameter sets in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Ty for answering, Greg. The reason i want to use the parameters given in the test case on Azure, is that I would like to avoid having to edit the same stuff twice :)

Comment: Why would you need to edit the same things twice? If you have automated the test, there is no need to keep a manual version of the test around.

Comment: Lets say that i have to run the same test with different logins. I have added the logins as parameters in Azure. If I also have to add them to the automated test case (In code), i will have to edit it 2 places, if I change the password.

Comment: Hm. True. I actually up-voted this question earlier, because we have selenium tests and just started using Azure DevOps as well. Our project will probably run into this situation too.

Comment: You probably will.. I have tried researching it, but haven't found anything useful yet..